# No Items in Populated ObservableCollection when accessed from another class

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, observablecollection, autosuggest

I'm trying to access an ObservableCollection that has already been populated inside another class (the viewModel). However, it always returns with nothing inside the ObservableCollection. I need this so that the collection can be sorted and searched. Interestingly, when I load the same ObservableCollection into an AutoSuggestBox, it displays the items in the ObservableCollection…

The code for sorting the Collection:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame currentFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        MainPage mainPage = currentFrame.Content as MainPage;
        mainPage.UpdateNavigationView(0);

        TasksViewModel viewModel = new TasksViewModel();
        int count = viewModel.searchableTaskTitles.Count();
        bool swapped = false;

        while (swapped == false)
        {
            swapped = true;
            int loopCount = 0;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(count);
            while (loopCount + 1 != count + 1)
            {
                if (string.Compare(viewModel.searchableTaskTitles.ElementAt(loopCount), viewModel.searchableTaskTitles.ElementAt(loopCount + 1)) == 1)
                {
                    string a = viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount];
                    viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount] = viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount + 1];
                    viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount + 1] = a;
                    swapped = false;
                }
                loopCount = loopCount + 1;
            }
            loopCount = 0;
        }
    }
```

The code for getting the data:

```
public class TasksViewModel
    {

        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> searchableTaskTitles = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();
        public List<string> taskTitles = new List<string>();

        public async void GetData()
        {
            string taskTitle;
            string taskImportance;
            string taskCompletion;
            string taskDesc;
            StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Tasks", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IReadOnlyCollection<StorageFile> fileNames = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

            foreach (StorageFile file in fileNames)
            {
                using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
                using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
                {
                    taskTitle = string.Format(streamReader.ReadLine());
                    taskImportance = string.Format(streamReader.ReadLine());
                    taskCompletion = string.Format(streamReader.ReadLine()) + "%";
                    taskDesc = string.Format(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                }

                this.searchableTaskTitles.Add(taskTitle);

                this.taskTitles.Add(taskTitle);
            }
        }

        public TasksViewModel()
        {
            GetData();
        }
    }
```

Just in case... the code for SearchQuerySubmitted for the AutoSuggestBox:

```
private void SearchQuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
            {
                SearchAutoSuggestBox.Text = args.ChosenSuggestion.ToString();
                string searchText = args.ChosenSuggestion.ToString();

                int clickedItem = 0;
                TasksViewModel viewModel = new TasksViewModel();
                foreach (string item in viewModel.taskTitles)
                {
                    if (searchText == item)
                    {
                        clickedItem = viewModel.taskTitles.IndexOf(item);
                    }
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(clickedItem);
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ViewTaskPage), clickedItem);
            }
        }
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your search query submitted method you're doing this:

```
TasksViewModel viewModel = new TasksViewModel();
```

The constructor calls `GetData` but this returns a `Task` which as it doesn't have a return type, it can't be awaited, and you're not even trying to wait for it to finish either.

You need to either ditch the async, or return a value and wait for it in the constructor.

You shouldn't be doing async work in the constructor anyway, so my recommendation would be to change this code, to:

```
TasksViewModel viewModel = new TasksViewModel();
await viewModel.GetData();
```

But be sure to have `GetData` actually return something, or awaiting won't work, because you can't await a void-returning async method.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) for more information on how to properly use async / await

Comment: @Anthony then don't do it in the constructor, make the constructor private, make it take the collection of data, and introduce a static `Task<TasksViewModel>` method on `TasksViewModel` that will call `GetData` asynchronously, and then return a new instance of the view model with the data supplied.

This way you can do `var vm = await TasksViewModel.Create()`

Answer (score 0):

You should not kick off an asynchronous operation in a constructor. This is a [bad practice](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

The `GetData()` method is still running when the constructor returns. Instead of calling it in the constructor, you could call it from your `OnNavigatedTo` method:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Frame currentFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    MainPage mainPage = currentFrame.Content as MainPage;
    mainPage.UpdateNavigationView(0);

    TasksViewModel viewModel = new TasksViewModel();
    await viewModel.GetData();
    int count = viewModel.searchableTaskTitles.Count();
    bool swapped = false;

    while (swapped == false)
    {
        swapped = true;
        int loopCount = 0;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(count);
        while (loopCount + 1 != count + 1)
        {
            if (string.Compare(viewModel.searchableTaskTitles.ElementAt(loopCount), viewModel.searchableTaskTitles.ElementAt(loopCount + 1)) == 1)
            {
                string a = viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount];
                viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount] = viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount + 1];
                viewModel.searchableTaskTitles[loopCount + 1] = a;
                swapped = false;
            }
            loopCount = loopCount + 1;
        }
        loopCount = 0;
    }
}
```

You should also change the return type of the `GetData()` method to `Task` for you to be able to await it. An `async` method should return `Task` or `Task<T>` unless it's an event handler. Please refer to @Stephen Cleary's [MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more information about best practices in asynchronous programming.